# MYSQL count: select ALL from users, count active/total ads (2 counts)

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have a table of users and a table of classifieds

I would like to select ALL users from the table with 2 counts:
- active classifieds (classifieds.status = 'A')
- all classifieds

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, count(c.id) as total_active, COUNT( c2.id ) AS total
FROM `users` u
LEFT join `classifieds` c ON c.user_id=u.id AND c.status = 'A'
LEFT join `classifieds` c2 ON c2.user_id=u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a CASE inside the COUNT. 
The ELSE case is implied NULL which is ignored by `COUNT(column)`

```
SELECT 
   u.*, 
   count(CASE WHEN c.status = 'A' THEN c.id END) as total_active, 
   COUNT(c.id) AS total
FROM 
    `users` u
    LEFT JOIN 
    `classifieds` c ON c.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY 
    u.id -- fix this
```

Also, standard SQL is to either group on or aggregate columns: the MySQL GROUP BY extensions can give misleading results because the engine *guesses* what you want.

Try this query with `SET SQL_MODE = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` to see what I mean...

Comment: wow, that was really fast! and it works! one typo though, you have one AND left in left join!

Thanks alot!